# Extract values from dataset to perform functions- multiple countries within dataset

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

My dataset looks as follows:

| Country | Year | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ireland | 2010 | 9 |
| Ireland | 2011 | 11 |
| Ireland | 2012 | 14 |
| Ireland | 2013 | 17 |
| Ireland | 2014 | 20 |
| France | 2011 | 15 |
| France | 2012 | 19 |
| France | 2013 | 21 |
| France | 2014 | 28 |
| Germany | 2008 | 17 |
| Germany | 2009 | 20 |
| Germany | 2010 | 19 |
| Germany | 2011 | 24 |
| Germany | 2012 | 27 |
| Germany | 2013 | 32 |

My goal is to create a new dataset which tells me the % increase from the first year of available data for a given country, compared to the most recent, which would look roughly as follows:

| Country | % increase |
| --- | --- |
| Ireland | 122 |
| France | 87 |
| Germany | 88 |

In essence, I need my code for each country in my dataset, to locate the smallest and largest value for year, then take the corresponding values within the value column and calculate the % increase.

I can do this manually, however I have a lot of countries in my dataset and am looking for a more elegant way to do it. I am trying to troubleshoot my code for this however I am not having much luck as of yet.

My code looks as follows at present:

```
df_1["Min_value"] = df.loc[df["Year"].min(),"Value"].iloc[0]
df_1["Max_value"] = df.loc[df["Year"].max(),"Value"].iloc[0]

df_1["% increase"] = ((df_1["Max_value"]-df_1["Min_value"])/df_1["Min_value"])*100
```

This returns an error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'iloc'

In addition to this it also has the issue that I cannot figure out a way to have the code to run individually for each country within my dataset, so this is another challenge which I am not entirely sure how to address.

Could I potentially go down the route of defining a particular function which could then be applied to each country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by `Country` and aggregate `min/max` for both `Year` and `Value`, then calculate [percentage change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) between `min` and `max` of the `Value`.

```
pct_df = df.groupby(['Country']).agg(['min', 'max'])['Value']\
    .apply(lambda x: x.pct_change().round(2) * 100, axis=1)\
    .drop('min', axis=1).rename(columns={'max':'% increase'}).reset_index()

print(pct_df)
```

The output:

```
    Country  % increase
0   France         87.0
1  Germany         88.0
2  Ireland        122.0
```